# Please help me to identify this plant, please!

Tags: identification

Hello again to the knowledgeable people; I have one more plant to identify in my garden. I have moved recently and seeded some plants but many different other plants are growing also. Please help me to find out if the below plant is a weed or a flower.

Thank you very much for your time!!

Cristina

[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: It reminds me of something, but at the moment, whatever it is is not coming to mind. I really am not sure whether this is a weed or not - its the bright green leaves that make me think it's not...when you say you 'seeded' some plants, do you mean you planted actual seeds, or small plants?

Comment: Thank you Bamboo for your time to answer to me. Yes, I have planted seeds for several flowers when the pots were empty, but now-even after watering and using plant food, it seams that only weeds are coming out. So, I think I need to change soil and start all over next year...Thank you for your time!

Comment: Couple of tips then -do not feed until any seeds you've planted have become plants, that is, about the size of the one in the image you've posted. Also better without the stones on top if you plant seeds...